# Rewrite example.txt to another based on the domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im using a multi-install for my webpage with two different domains and i need for each domain a unique robots.txt

like
https://www.domain1.tdl/robots.txt should use the https://www.domain1.tdl/robots_domain1.txt

and

https://www.domain2.tdl/robots.txt should use the https://www.domain2.tdl/robots_domain2.txt

Comment: Untested, but something like `RewriteRule ^/robots.txt$ /robots_%{HTTP_HOST}.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrites in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.tdl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain1.tdl/robots_domain1.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.tdl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.domain2.tdl/robots_domain2.txt [L]
```